# Is there a end user difference between compiling with 4.5 and 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

I'm working on a nuget package and want to support multiple .net versions. After having a look at Newtonsoft.Json i figured out how to build the project structure properly to reuse code files.

What i'm wondering about now is : Is there a difference for a consumer of my package between me compiling with 4.5 or 4.5.2? I know 4.5.2 contains bugfixes and other things - But they are both executed by the same runtime platform.

Let's say the consumer builds his project with 4.5.2, won't my 4.5 compiled package also have its bugfixes applied by the consumer runtime environment or am i understanding it wrong in that perspective?

Just looking for clarification, because i'm not sure if what i'm presuming is correct.

Comment: No, only the reference assemblies matter for building, they contain no code.  You should target 4.0, your nuget package can be used with any version >= 4.0. Build a 4.5 specific version if you want to support 4.5 specific features, like *async*. Very unlikely you'll find anything in 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 that you'd want to take advantage of, the additions are few.

Comment: @HansPassant I see. So unless i use 4.5+ things there is no good reason to add a project for it. Thanks. that helps.